# Group a series of events into one line with a start and end time

Tags: sql, presto, gaps-and-islands, trino

This question regards SQL (specifically using Presto).

I have a situation where agents are interacting with tasks (commenting, taking ownership, adding tags, etc.) and I'm trying to group each series of interactions into one line with a summarized start and end time.

Basically, the table currently looks something like this:

| Task Name | Agent Name | Event Type | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Computer Repair Help | Dave | Claim | 2:35PM |
| Computer Repair Help | Dave | Comment | 2:37PM |
| Computer Repair Help | Dave | Tag | 2:39PM |
| Computer Repair Help | Dave | Pass | 2:45PM |
| Computer Repair Help | Susie | Claim | 2:56PM |
| Computer Repair Help | Susie | Tag | 2:58PM |
| Computer Repair Help | Susie | Pass | 3:02PM |
| Computer Repair Help | Dave | Claim | 3:05PM |
| Computer Repair Help | Dave | Comment | 3:08PM |
| Computer Repair Help | Dave | Comment | 3:11PM |
| Computer Repair Help | Dave | Close | 3:16PM |

But I am hoping to get something like this:

| Task Name | Agent Name | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Computer Repair Help | Dave | 2:35PM | 2:45PM |
| Computer Repair Help | Susie | 2:56PM | 3:02PM |
| Computer Repair Help | Dave | 3:05PM | 3:16PM |

I've tried partitioning by task name and agent name to get the first and last row of each interaction, but the main problem is that if an agent has two interaction windows, it will give me the total range of all their interactions instead of separating like in the example. Not sure how to tell the query to treat it like a new interaction after every agent name change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated... have been bashing my head against this for weeks and it seems like there must be some simple solution I'm not seeing. Thanks!

Comment: what's the definition of start and end?

Comment: The time of their first event in the series and the time of their last event in the series

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this using [`MATCH_RECOGNIZE`](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/match-recognize.html), which is available in recent versions of [Trino](https://trino.io) ([formerly known as Presto SQL](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html)):

```sql
WITH data(task, agent, event, ts) AS (
    VALUES ('Computer Repair Help', 'Dave', 'Claim', '2:35PM'),
           ('Computer Repair Help', 'Dave', 'Comment', '2:37PM'),
           ('Computer Repair Help', 'Dave', 'Tag', '2:39PM'),
           ('Computer Repair Help', 'Dave', 'Pass', '2:45PM'),
           ('Computer Repair Help', 'Susie', 'Claim', '2:56PM'),
           ('Computer Repair Help', 'Susie', 'Tag', '2:58PM'),
           ('Computer Repair Help', 'Susie', 'Pass', '3:02PM'),
           ('Computer Repair Help', 'Dave', 'Claim', '3:05PM'),
           ('Computer Repair Help', 'Dave', 'Comment', '3:08PM'),
           ('Computer Repair Help', 'Dave', 'Comment', '3:11PM'),
           ('Computer Repair Help', 'Dave', 'Close', '3:16PM')
)
SELECT task, agent, start_time, end_time
FROM data MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
        PARTITION BY task
        ORDER BY ts
        MEASURES
            FIRST(M.agent) AS agent,
            FIRST(M.ts) AS start_time,
            LAST(M.ts) AS end_time
        ONE ROW PER MATCH
        AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW
        PATTERN (M+)
        DEFINE M AS agent = FIRST(agent)
    )
```

=>

```
         task         | agent | start_time | end_time
----------------------+-------+------------+----------
 Computer Repair Help | Dave  | 2:35PM     | 2:45PM
 Computer Repair Help | Susie | 2:56PM     | 3:02PM
 Computer Repair Help | Dave  | 3:05PM     | 3:16PM
(3 rows)
```

The basic idea is to:

- Partition the dataset by task and order it by time
- Match sequences of rows whose agent is equal to the agent of the first row in the sequence
- Extract the time of the first and last events in the sequence

You can find more details about MATCH_RECOGNIZE here:

- Documentation: https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/match-recognize.html
- Blog post: https://trino.io/blog/2021/05/19/row_pattern_matching.html
- Podcast: https://trino.io/episodes/23.html

Comment: Just read the trino story. Thank you for your contributions to open-source. I'll take a closer look at this project. Hopefully I will be able to add some value if not now, later.

Comment: Dang, this function seems so useful but I'm using AWS Athena which doesn't seem to allow it, perhaps we are not on the most current engine or something. I'm still too new to all this to know why but thank you so much for the answer and for making me aware of this, looking forward to getting to implement it some day!

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved as a "gaps and islands" problem. I assumed based on your dataset that each new set of interactions started with a `Claim`.

As such the `CTE` (which may also be rewritten as a subquery) used the `SUM` window function to create groups with the assistance of a case expression. The final projection grouped the data using this `GroupNum` (where `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` is optional), Task and Event Type in order to find the `StartTime` as `MIN(Time)` and `EndTime` as `MAX(Time)` for each group.

You may try the following:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        SUM(
            CASE
                WHEN EventType='Claim' THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
        ) OVER (
            PARTITION BY TaskName, AgentName 
            ORDER BY Time 
            RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
        ) as GroupNum
    FROM
        my_table
)
SELECT
    TaskName,
    AgentName,
    MIN(Time) as StartTime,
    MAX(Time) as EndTime
FROM
    CTE
GROUP BY
    TaskName,
    AgentName,
    GroupNum
```

| TaskName | AgentName | StartTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Computer Repair Help | Dave | 2:35PM | 2:45PM |
| Computer Repair Help | Susie | 2:56PM | 3:02PM |
| Computer Repair Help | Dave | 3:05PM | 3:16PM |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f7CHDousAAjPpcGpxknf6R/0)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Just tested this out and it worked on my end, probably just replaced like 100 lines of absurdly inefficient code (so many same table joins on row number - 1 etc) with this logic haha, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: what if there isn't any identifier like "claim" OR 3 identifiers, like walk, run, idle?

Comment: @AliDemirci Can you create another question with a reproducible sample dataset and expected results. I would be able to better understand and respond there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant of gaps-and-islands problem. Using `lag()` you can find where the value changes and then do a cumulative sum to assign groups.

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES   
('Computer Repair Help' ,'Dave','   Claim'  ,'2:35PM'),
('Computer Repair Help' ,'Dave','   Comment'    ,'2:37PM'),
('Computer Repair Help' ,'Dave','   Tag',   '2:39PM'),
('Computer Repair Help' ,'Dave','   Pass'   ,'2:45PM'),
('Computer Repair Help' ,'Susie','  Claim'  ,'2:56PM'),
('Computer Repair Help' ,'Susie','  Tag','2:58PM'),
('Computer Repair Help' ,'Susie','  Pass'   ,'3:02PM'),
('Computer Repair Help' ,'Dave  ','Claim'   ,'3:05PM'),
('Computer Repair Help' ,'Dave  ','Comment' ,'3:08PM'),
('Computer Repair Help' ,'Dave  ','Comment' ,'3:11PM'),
('Computer Repair Help' ,'Dave  ','Close'   ,'3:16PM')
                   
 ) AS t (task, name, event_type, time))


select task, name, min(time) as start_time, max(time) as end_time
from (
         select *,
                sum(case when name = prev_id then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by task, name order by time) as grp
         from (
                  select task, name, time,
                         lag(name) over (order by time) as prev_id
                  from dataset
              )
     )
group by task, name, grp
```

Output:

| task | name | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Computer Repair Help | Dave | 2:35PM | 2:45PM |
| Computer Repair Help | Susie | 2:56PM | 3:02PM |
| Computer Repair Help | Dave | 3:05PM | 3:16PM |

Note that possibly you will need to parse your time into actual one.

Comment: Gaps-and-islands, I knew there had to be a name for this situation but didn't know what to google haha... a conundrum as old as time. This lag function seems so useful, can't wait to try implementing your advice. Thank you so much!